# Meaning of "while (!(cin >> x) || (cin.peek() != '\n') || x <= 0)" on C++

Tags: c++

I got a code, for avoidance of any signs input, despite "int" characters.

Please, explain me step by step what exactly is happening here?

```
    while (!(cin >> x) || (cin.peek() != '\n') || x <= 0)
            // What is happening here?
        {
            cin.clear();
            // What is happening here?
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
            // What is happening here?
            cout << "Error. Not a Natural number. Try one more time" << endl;
```

Comment: I upvoted this question because I don't think what happens here is obvious to a person new to the language or easy to search.

Comment: @dre that may be true, but the problem with "explain this to me" questions is that without knowing what knowledge OP is missing, how can we write a helpful answer? Do they know what `cin >> x` does? Do they know how the return from `cin.operator>>()` works? Do they know that the bang there is doing an implicit conversion of that return to bool and then flipping it? Have they tried looking up what `cin.clear()` does? What confused them in the docs? Do you see what I'm saying?

Answer (score 2):

The code is simply validating input in a loop, discarding unwanted input.

---

`while (...)`

Should be self-explanatory.  Loops until its operand evaluates to `false`.

`||`

The ["inclusive OR" logical operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical).  Evaluates to `true` if at least 1 of its 2 operands evaluate to `true`, otherwise to `false`.

`!(cin >> x)`

Reads a value into `x`.  If the read fails because of an I/O error, or if the entered value does not match the data type of `x`, `cin` is put into an error state. `>>` returns a reference to the `std::ostream` it is called on (ie, `cin`).  Applying `operator!` to that stream will evaluate to `true` if the stream is in an error state, otherwise to `false`.

`(cin.peek() != '\n')`

Looks to see if the next entered character is a line break (such as from typing in <kbd>Enter</kbd>) without removing the character from the input buffer.

Due to ["short-circuit evaluation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), this expression is not reached if `>>` fails to read a value into `x`.

`x <= 0`

Should be self-explanatory.  Checks if the number is negative or zero.

Due to ["short-circuit evaluation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), this expression is not reached if `>>` fails to read a value into `x`, or `peek()` does not return `'\n'`.

`cin.clear();`

Resets `cin`'s error state, such as if `>>` failed.

`while (cin.get() != '\n');`

Reads and discards input until a line break (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) is encountered.

`cout << "Error. Not a Natural number. Try one more time" << endl`

Should be self-explanatory.  Simply printing out a message for the user to see.

---

So, if the user enters anything that is not a number, or the number is not followed immediate by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or the number is <= 0, all input up to the next <kbd>Enter</kbd> is discarded, and the loop repeats to try to read in a new number.

The loop ends when the user types in a number that is > 0 and immediately followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

On a side note:

`while (cin.get() != '\n');`

Is typically coded using `cin.ignore()` instead:

`cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: "Due to "short-circuit evaluation", this expression is reached only if >> successfully read a value into x, and if peek() returned '\n'." - that would be the case if there were `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: @Fureeish while a `false` value short-circuits `&&`, the opposite is true for `||` (that is, any `true` value will short-circuit). So Remy is correct in saying that if either `!(cin >> x)` is true OR `(cin.peek() != '\n')` is true, `x <= 0` will never be checked because of short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @scohe001 my bad, mixed the negations in the sentence and in the code.

Comment: @Fureeish I updated my answer to clarify those statements.